# IMU_GPS robot_localization and navsat_transform_node

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I have some car GPS data (about 1Hz) in my hand, and there is an electronic device built-in IMU in the car to collect IMU data (about 1KHz). The direction of the IMU on the car is the Z axis forward, the X axis right, and the Y axis point to the ground.However, because GPS will drift (some have left the road), it can not be used as accurate data for positioning algorithms.So I decided to use the robot_localization package to put the two kinds of data together, generating new, more accurate GPS data for future use.And I have referred to this post's answer (https://answers.ros.org/question/200071/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot_localization/). But my current program can not get the output (even if it is not accurate), I hope you can help me analyze the reasons. In addition, I finally hope to get GPS or UTM data. Thank you!

the rqt pic is here:

[image: Imgur]

the launch file is here:

```
<launch>
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robot_localization)/params/ekf_imu_gps.yaml" />
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_se_map" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform" clear_params="true">
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_map"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

the pramater file is here:

```
ekf_se_map:
  frequency: 30
  sensor_timeout: 0.1
  two_d_mode: true
  transform_time_offset: 0.0
  transform_timeout: 0.0
  print_diagnostics: true
  debug: false

  map_frame: map
  odom_frame: odom
  base_link_frame: base_link
  world_frame: odom

  # odom0: odometry/gps
  odom0: odometry/gps
  odom0_config: [true, true, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  imu0: imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

  use_control: false

  process_noise_covariance:
  [1e-9, 0, 0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]

  initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,   0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,   0,     0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,   0,    0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9,  0,
                                0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]



navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0.05288347 # For lat/long 55.944831, -3.186998
  yaw_offset: 1.570796327  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: false
  wait_for_datum: false
```

next is the scirpt I use to make bag file from the csv data:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import rospy
import rosbag
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
def make_imu_data(a,b,t,n):
    a=np.array(a)
    b=np.array(b)
    message1=Imu()
    message1.header.seq=n
    message1.header.stamp.secs=float(t.split(".")[0])
    message1.header.stamp.nsecs=float(t.split(".")[1])*1e3
    message1.header.frame_id='odom'
    message1.orientation.x=0
    message1.orientation.y=0
    message1.orientation.z=0
    message1.orientation.w=0
    message1.orientation_covariance=np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1])
    message1.linear_acceleration.x=float(a[0])
    message1.linear_acceleration.y=float(a[1])
    message1.linear_acceleration.z=float(a[2])
    message1.linear_acceleration_covariance=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    message1.angular_velocity.x=float(b[0])
    message1.angular_velocity.y=float(b[1])
    message1.angular_velocity.z=float(b[2])
    message1.angular_velocity_covariance=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    return message1

def make_gps_data(latitude,longitude,t,i):
    message2=NavSatFix()
    message2.header.seq=i
    message2.header.stamp.secs=float(t.split(".")[0])
    message2.header.stamp.nsecs=float(t.split(".")[1])*1e3
    message2.header.frame_id='/gps'
    message2.status.status=1
    message2.status.service=1
    message2.longitude=float(longitude)
    message2.latitude=float(latitude)
    message2.altitude=np.NAN
    message2.position_covariance=np.array([0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.56])
    message2.position_covariance_type=0
    return message2

imufile='/home/Desktop/imu.txt'
gpsfile='/home/Desktop/gps.txt'
with open(gpsfile) as dataset:
    row_numer=1
    with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'w') as bag:
        for line in dataset.readlines():
            gps_data=line.split()
            # print imu_data,row_numer
            row_numer=row_numer+1
            msg=make_gps_data(gps_data[2],gps_data[1],gps_data[0],row_numer)
            # print msg.header.stamp
            bag.write('/gps/fix',msg,msg.header.stamp)

with open(imufile) as dataset:
    row_numer=1
    with rosbag.Bag('test.bag', 'a') as bag:
        for line in dataset.readlines():
            imu_data=line.split()
            # print imu_data,row_numer
            row_numer=row_numer+1
            msg=make_imu_data(imu_data[1:4],imu_data[4:7],imu_data[0],row_numer)
            # print msg.angular_velocity
            bag.write('/imu/data',msg,msg.header.stamp)
```

the imu data is here:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 9199
  stamp: 
    secs: 9
    nsecs: 194340000
  frame_id: "odom"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 0.0
orientation_covariance: [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -3.067016
  y: -4.959106
  z: -1.815796
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.032837
  y: -1.048462
  z: -0.060669
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

the GPS data is here:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 23
  stamp: 
    secs: 21
    nsecs:     93000
  frame_id: "/gps"
status: 
  status: 1
  service: 1
latitude: 47.347427
longitude: 8.721068
altitude: nan
position_covariance: [0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.64, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.56]
position_covariance_type: 0
---
```

I really hope Tom Moore can help me,thank you very much.
All the files I metioned above can be downlaoded from here:[google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xvk2j080roVToFX-UrCk_htOEsun3CmM)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284325/imu_gps---robot_localization-and-navsat_transform_node/) by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omoyouo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33819/omoyouo/) on 2018-03-09**:
the new bag file is here:[NEW_bagfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJ-JFU0yadwOdwN4FTwAM09S-l3oHMIv/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't looked at the bag data, but just a few things I note looking at your data and configuration.

1. Linear acceleration: I'd set them all to *false* for your IMU. The filter does not have active bias correction, so unless you have a velocity reference (e.g., wheel encoder or visual odometry), the integration of acceleration data will cause your state estimate to start running away rapidly. It'll snap back whenever it gets a GPS measurement, but the state estimate will get progressively worse.
2. Change your IMU message `frame_id` to `imu_link`. Also, what units are your IMU velocities and the `static_transform_publisher` in? [ROS uses radians](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), and those look suspiciously like degrees.
3. If your IMU is mounted as you say, then I'd expect this. Keep in mind that `tf` and `tf2` assume that the order is `X Y Z yaw pitch roll`, though I believe they are applied extrinsically with roll, then pitch, then yaw. Experiment with values here and look at the frame in rviz to confirm.

   ```
   <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="transform" args="0 0 0 -1.5707963268 0 -1.5707963268  base_link imu_link" />
   ```
4. Get rid of the leading slash in your GPS message.
5. Did you define a *base_link*->*gps* transform? You're going to need one, if you gave your GPS message a `frame_id`. There is a bug at the time of this writing, though, so I suggest making the transform the identity (all zeros) for now. Also, get rid of the leading slash in your GPS frame ('/gps').

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1